# How can I generate a random string in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random

I want to create a string with random length and random characters, only [a-z][A-Z] and numbers. Is there something built in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

There isn't much to add to the answers of @Phonon and @dantswain, except that the range of `[a-Z]`,`[A-Z]` can be generated in less painful way, and `randi` can be used to create integer random values.

```
 symbols = ['a':'z' 'A':'Z' '0':'9'];
 MAX_ST_LENGTH = 50;
 stLength = randi(MAX_ST_LENGTH);
 nums = randi(numel(symbols),[1 stLength]);
 st = symbols (nums);
```

Comment: [Wasn't explicitly asked by the OP, but for anyone who cares: The resulting distribution will not be uniform, as there is a bias towards shorter strings.]

Answer (score 10):

This should work

```
s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

%find number of random characters to choose from
numRands = length(s); 

%specify length of random string to generate
sLength = 50;

%generate random string
randString = s( ceil(rand(1,sLength)*numRands) )
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a nicer way to achieve this without the long string?

Comment: minor mistake: you should use `ceil` instead of `round`, otherwise you may have index zero, which is not allowed in MATLAB

Answer (score 6):

I started to write this before I realized you wanted [A-Z][a-z] and [0-9].  For that, @Phonon's answer is good.

Just as an alternative, this will generate random ASCII characters in the full range of readable characters from space (32) to tilde (126):

```
length = 10;
random_string = char(floor(94*rand(1, length)) + 32);
```

Comment: With a bit of tweaking, I still find this a good simple single-line solution for simple needs. I am using `random_string = char(floor(26*rand(1, 10)) + 65);` which gives me 10 capital letters starting with capital A (which is 65th position in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)), going through all 26 letters of English alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the built-in function *tempname*? For example, these two lines will give you a randon string in rand_string:

```
temp_name = tempname
[temp1, rand_string] = fileparts(temp_name)
```

Please note that rand_string will also contain underscore character "_".

Comment: Please note also that the first 2 letters in the generated name will be `tp` and all the other letters will be `a,b,c,d,e` or `f`. `tempname` doesn't actually generate random strings at all, it generates (modified) UUIDs.

Comment: `tempname` gave me a full temp path as prefix `C:\Users\JoeDoe\Temp\tp7eff7653_0873_4c68_85ba_a51d5d9fe71f`.