# How can I initialize a general string with unknown length but known capped length in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, function

I'm trying to build a function that will manipulate a string. I'm confident that my syntax works well. However, I can only really do this in a workspace when I manually insert a string. I would like to initialize a general string in a function. The string can have anywhere from 0 to 1000 characters. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what about the answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918051/how-can-i-generate-a-random-string-in-matlab) question?

Comment: Do you want to initialize a blank string?  That can be done with `s = repmat(' ', 1, N);` where `N` is whatever number of characters you want.  I don't quite understand what you want though... some examples to illustrate your point would help.