# link php with matlab

Tags: php, matlab

IS it possible to connect MATLAB with php code? because I want to get a value from the php which will generate when the MATLAB code will run.

Comment: I bet there are more clever solutions, but did you try saving it to disk and reading it from the other platform?

Comment: I don't want to save the password in anywhere. that's why I want to directly take the password from the generation stage. @Dev-iL

Comment: If you have the PHP serve it using a webservice, you can use MATLAB to access this web page (or RESTful service), and get the value. Of course, you will have to synchronize these apps somehow (i.e. make MATLAB aware that a new key is available), which is another problem...

Comment: any of these codes aren't connected with any web page. so finally? there's no way ?

Comment: Why not generating your key directly in matlab ?

Comment: I couldn't. I searched about it, but I found random number generation IN MATLAB, but as a key I used to generate random string(combine with number,Alphabet, signs) and also unique in php, @Gourgandine

Comment: And this is not what you want ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918051/how-can-i-generate-a-random-string-in-matlab

Comment: Thank u very much. I got it @Gourgandine